# Home link in 2017

Tags: navigation

In 2017, is home link still needed in a navbar or a logo will suffice? Is there any recent research on how users are familiar with the logo linking to the home page?

Comment: What happened recently in terms of UX that makes you wonder if the Home link is still relevant?

Comment: Not recently, but most of the info I can find is like 4-5 years old and may be not relevant for today's reality.

Comment: It depends on the context.  On a website then a logo may be all that is needed, but in a web based application, "home" may be customisable per user and therefore would justify having a link to each possible place which could be home

Answer (score 3):

**This depends on the target audience of your project.** You can do tests to know if you need a separate button to go home.

Nowadays this is very common and many people are accustomed to clicking on the logo and going to the home page.

You can learn more about it here:

https://designanduxtips.wordpress.com/2015/03/23/home-button-vs-logo-link/
https://www.webdesignerdepot.com/2015/08/the-ux-case-against-the-home-button/